# How to find files that came from another computer

Tags: windows, windows-search, metadata

In a file's properties dialog you know that message *This file came from another computer and may be blocked...*

I want a Windows 7 search query to find files that came from other computers, and files that came from this one. For instance looking for a code snippet `javascript onclick type:.js date: earlier this year <file made by me>`. Unless I somehow exclude the various program files that match the query, I get too many irrelevant result.

I can't search for `author:` because it's not a good proxy (files either don't have that metadata or my author name isn't constant over the years).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerShell for this. Files originating from the Internet have an alternate data stream called Zone.Identifier. As of PowerShell 3.0, `Get-Item` supports the `-Stream` parameter, which allows viewing of ADS. If you're running Windows 8, you should already have a capable version of PowerShell built-in. If you're on Windows 7, you'll need to download an update from Microsoft's website. The latest version is currently PowerShell 4.0.

Once you've got a capable version of PowerShell installed, the following command will list all files in the current folder (and subfolders) which have the Zone.Identifier ADS:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Get-Item -Stream Zone.Identifier -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object FileName
```

Expanded, with comments:

```
# Get all items in the current folder and its subfolders.
Get-ChildItem -Recurse|

# Get the Zone.Identifier ADS for each item. Suppress error output.
# Errors are suppressed here because otherwise the screen will fill with non-critical errors for all the files that *don't* have the Zone.Identifier ADS - i.e.: Files that aren't from the Internet.
Get-Item -Stream Zone.Identifier -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |

# Display only the FileName property of each object returned.
Select-Object FileName
```

"Golfed" version:

```
ls -Rec|gi -S Zone.Identifier -ErrorA SilentlyContinue|select FileName
```

- `ls`, `gi`, and `select` are built-in aliases for `Get-ChildItem`, `Get-Item`, and `Select-Object`, respectively.
- `-Recurse`, `-Stream`, and `-ErrorAction` were truncated to the minimum length required to uniquely identify the parameter names.